Does Files configuration in Digital Experience have any effect on files uploaded via Apex?
I wonder if this setting in Digital Experience > Administration > Preferences section has any effect on files uploaded via Apex (using lightning-input type="file" and base64 encoded string)?

If not, then how can I make sure that users don't upload files more than 2 MB? I know that it is not possible to upload a file bigger than 4 MB via Apex, but in my case the maximum file size is lower. Can I rely on Blob.valueof(base64FileString).size() method? In the documentation it is said that size():

Returns the number of characters in the Blob.

HTML
<lightning-input
  type="file"
  label="Upload your file"
  accept={acceptedFormats}
  onchange={handleFilesChange}
 ></lightning-input>

<lightning-button variant="brand" label="submit" title="Submit" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>

JS
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import uploadFile from "@salesforce/apex/GuestFileUploadController.uploadFile";

export default class UploadFile extends LightningElement {

    fileData;
    
    get acceptedFormats() {
        return [".pdf", ".jpeg", ".jpg"];
    }
    
    handleClick(){
        const {base64, filename} = this.fileData
        uploadFile({ base64, filename });
    }

    handleFilesChange(event) {
        const file = event.target.files[0]
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
            this.fileData = {
                filename: file.name,
                base64: base64
            };
            console.log("handleFilesChange: ", this.fileData);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
}   

Apex
public without sharing class GuestFileUploadController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void uploadFile(String base64, String filename) {

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);
        cv.Title = filename;
        cv.PathOnClient = filename;
        
        insert cv;
    }
}


wouldn't this be answered by a simple experiment using a testmethod an `0123456789'.repeat(200000) and insert a ContentVersion?


I wonder if this setting in Digital Experience > Administration > Preferences section has any effect on files uploaded via Apex (using lightning-input type="file" and base64 encoded string)?

This setting only affects standard file uploads. If you save files in Apex with a custom LWC, then it is your own responsibility to check the file size.

I know that it is not possible to upload a file bigger than 4 MB via Apex, but in my case the maximum file size is lower.

Note that the entire payload to Apex is limited to 4MB, and since you're encoding the binary data as base-64, there's a 3:4 (33%) increase in the payload size. This limits the file to just under 3,000,000 bytes (approximately 3MB/2.86MiB), because the payload is encoded in JSON, so things like the file name will affect the maximum number of bytes the file can have.

Can I rely on Blob.valueof(base64FileString).size() method?

The string is 33% larger than the actual file size. Instead, you would use:
EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64FileString).size()

That said, you can save the call to the server by checking the file size in the client:
handleClick(){
    const {base64, filename} = this.fileData
    if(base64.length <= 2666667) {
        uploadFile({ base64, filename });
    } else {
        this.displayUploadError();
    }
}

Or even when the file is selected:
reader.onload = () => {
    const base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
    if(base64.length <= 2666667) {
        this.refs.fileUpload.setCustomValidity('');
        this.fileData = {
            filename: file.name,
            base64: base64
        };
    } else {
        this.refs.fileUpload.setCustomValidity('File is too large to upload');
    }
}

Note: I've used this.refs in this example. You would need to modify your template as follows:
<lightning-input
  type="file"
  label="Upload your file"
  accept={acceptedFormats}
  onchange={handleFilesChange}
  lwc:ref="fileUpload"
 ></lightning-input>

